# Subquery retorna mais de um valor

Tags: mysql, query, stored-procedures

Ao realizar um update dentro de uma procedure, aparece a mensagem dizendo que a subquery de comparação trás mais de um resultado. 
A subquery foi testada e trás apenas um resultado, uma vez que busca pelo id do Exame e este é único para cada linha da tabela.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE realizaAprovacao (IN codigoExame INT)
    BEGIN

        IF(SELECT nota FROM Exame WHERE idExame = codigoExame) >= 60 THEN
            UPDATE Exame SET statusAprovacao = TRUE WHERE idExame = codigoExame;
        ELSE 
            UPDATE Exame SET statusAprovacao = FALSE WHERE idExame = codigoExame;
        END IF;
    END
$$
```

O parâmetro codigoExame é um int passado na chamada da procedure, e portanto corresponde à um único valor. 
Já conferi os valores inseridos na tabela Exame, e não possuem linhas com códigos repetidos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Além do que a própria mensagem sugere, eu não consigo imaginar outro motivo para esse erro estar sendo disparado.

No entanto, você pode contornar isso de outras formas.

Por exemplo:

**Coloque um `Limit 1`**

```
IF(SELECT nota FROM Exame WHERE idExame = codigoExame LIMIT 1) >= 60 THEN
```

**Não avalie. Simplesmente altere**

```
UPDATE Exame
SET statusAprovacao = CASE WHEN nota >= 60 THEN true ELSE false END
WHERE idExame = codigoExame;
```

Espero ter ajudado.